# How to add unsupported CSS properties to element.style in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I create a div element and set its style properties in JavaScript:

```
var popupDiv = document.createElement("div");
popupDiv.style.background = "#fff";
popupDiv.style.border = "1px solid #e8e8e8";
popupDiv.style.padding = "20px";
popupDiv.style.position = "fixed";
...
```

But I also want to add:

```
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none; 
user-select: none;
```

So I tried:

```
popupDiv.style.webkitUserSelect = "none";
popupDiv.style.mozUserSelect = "none";  
popupDiv.style.msUserSelect = "none";
popupDiv.style.userSelect= "none";
```

But only the "user-select: none;" property gets set correctly...so my question is...how do I add these "unsupported" css properties via JS?

(Setting them directly in css/inline is not an option.)

Comment: why do you want to add it if they're not supported? Ah or I misread, your problem is that the first letter of moz and webkit browser-prefix are UpperCase (`WebkitUserSelect`)

Comment: @Nit Property names seem to be right. I just checked on IE, and it does support `msUserSelect`.

Comment: You may possibly pre-define a class like `.noselect { -moz-user-select: none; -webkit-user-select: none; -ms-user-select: none; }` and add it to the `classList` property dynamically like `element.classList.add("noselect");`

Comment: Yes, uppercasing the properties solved my problem, thanks guys!